# Angular 2.0 and ng-style

Tags: javascript, angular

I am building an Angular 2.0 component and I want to control it's style dynamically (using `ng-style`). After a quick view on Angular 2's docs i tried this:

```
<div class="theme-preview" ng-style="{'font-size': fontSize}">
  {{fontSize}}
</div>
```

And saw that the size is actually printed inside the div but did not affected the style. `fontSize` is one of component's property bindings', meaning the component gets it from its parent like this:

```
<my-component [font-size]="size" />
```

While inside the component I have:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'XXX',
  properties: ['fontSize']
})
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you have a plnkr to reproduce it?

Comment: sorry, no. I will try to create one. 10x

Answer (score 52, accepted):

## Update

People still reach this answer, so I've updated the plnkr to beta.1. Two things have changed so far

- NgStyle is no longer necessary to be explicitly added in directives property. It's part of the common directives that are added by default.
- The syntax has changed, now it must be camel case.

**Example**

```js
@Component({
  selector : 'my-cmp',
  template : `
    <div class="theme-preview" [ngStyle]="{'font-size': fontSize+'px'}">
   {{fontSize}}
  </div>`
})
class MyCmp {
  @Input('font-size') fontSize;
}

@Component({ 
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [MyCmp],
  template: `
    <my-cmp [font-size]="100"></my-cmp>
  `
})
```

See this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wf3vX8Ys8cFTJF212aou?p=preview) (*Updated to beta.1*)

Answer (score 19):

For specific style, you can also use this:

```
<div class="theme-preview" [style.font-size]="fontSize+'px'">
```

Comment: or `<div class="theme-preview" [style.font-size.px]="fontSize">` ;-)

Comment: what about mixing units e.g calculating a height on % and px?

Comment: @artdias90 You can't calculate with different units. You can set the unit like in my comment or like in the answer. JS can only calculate with plain numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is actually working on latest version of angular right now 4, the syntax actually changed, please notice the *[ngStyle]*

```
.color-box {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

<div class="color-box" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': your.model.object.color_code}"></div>
```