# How and where to use ::ng-deep?

Tags: css, angular, angular-template

How and where can one use `::ng-deep` in Angular 4?

Actually I want to overwrite some of the CSS properties of the child components from the parent components. Moreover is it supported on IE11?

Comment: Since `/deep/` and `::ng-deep` are both deprecated, I suggest you to take alook to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49308475/2275011 and comments for more details and solutions.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Usually  **`/deep/ “shadow-piercing”`** combinator  can be used to force a style down to **`child components`**. This selector had an alias >>> and now has another one called ::ng-deep.

since **`/deep/ combinator`** has been deprecated,  it is recommended to use `::ng-deep`

**For example:**

```
<div class="overview tab-pane" id="overview" role="tabpanel" [innerHTML]="project?.getContent( 'DETAILS')"></div>
```

and **`css`**

```
.overview {
    ::ng-deep {
        p {
            &:last-child {
                margin-bottom: 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it will be applied to child components

Comment: Is it support for IE11?

Comment: Angular does the parsing of it - so you don't need to worry about compatibility.

Comment: is it only for child components? as i remember and as i see in another comment, it's Also for dom elements outside component.

Comment: I can confirm it does parent components as well... Just had the case and was annoyed by that.

Answer (score 158):

I would emphasize the importance of limiting the `::ng-deep` to only children of a component by requiring the parent to be an encapsulated css class.

For this to work it's important to use the `::ng-deep` after the parent, not before otherwise it would apply to all the classes with the same name the moment the component is loaded.

Using the `:host` keyword before `::ng-deep` will handle this automatically:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-layout
```

---

Alternatively you can achieve the same behavior by adding a component scoped CSS class before the `::ng-deep` keyword:

```
.my-component ::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-layout {
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

Component template:

```
<h1 class="my-component">
    <mat-checkbox ....></mat-checkbox>
</h1>
```

---

Resulting (Angular generated) css will then include the uniquely generated name and apply only to its own component instance:

```
.my-component[_ngcontent-c1] .mat-checkbox-layout {
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

Comment: man, your answer `my-component ::ng-deep...` just saved my day. I spent all day trying to apply a style for my component with ng-deep and was overriding my all components, from my entire application.

Comment: Worth noting:
"In order to scope the specified style to the current component and all its descendants [but not globally], be sure to include the :host selector before ::ng-deep."
From: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

Comment: Should be the accepted answer given the precise explanations

Answer (score 135):

### USAGE

`::ng-deep`, `>>>` and `/deep/` disable view encapsulation for specific CSS rules, in other words, it gives you access to DOM elements, which are not in your component's HTML. For example, if you're using Angular Material (or any other third-party library like this), some generated elements are outside of your component's area (such as [**dialog**](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)) and you can't access those elements directly or using a regular CSS way. If you want to change the styles of those elements, you can use one of those three things, for example:

```
::ng-deep .mat-dialog {
  /* styles here */
}
```

For now Angular team recommends making *"deep"* manipulations only with **EMULATED** view encapsulation.

### DEPRECATION

*"deep"* manipulations are actually [**deprecated**](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) too, **BUT** it's still working for now, because Angular does pre-processing support (don't rush to refuse `::ng-deep` today, take a look at [**deprecation practices**](https://angular.io/guide/releases#deprecation-practices) first).

Anyway, before following this way, I recommend you to take a look at *disabling view encapsulation* approach (which is not ideal too, it allows your styles to leak into other components), but in some cases, it's a better way. If you decided to disable view encapsulation, it's strongly recommended to use specific classes to avoid CSS rules intersection, and finally, avoid a mess in your stylesheets. It's really easy to disable right in the component's `.ts` file:

```
@Component({
  selector: '',
  template: '',
  styles: [''],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None  // Use to disable CSS Encapsulation for this component
})
```

You can find more info about the view encapsulation in [**this**](https://coryrylan.com/blog/css-encapsulation-with-angular-components) article.

Comment: Disabling view encapsulation applies all CSS in your component globally.

Comment: Don't use `ViewEncapsulation.None`! It will make a lot of damage by making those styles possible to leak into other components.

Comment: To add: it will NOT unload the CSS once the component is unloaded either, aka super inconsistent and break-y CSS

Comment: The `::ng-deep` feature seems to have been removed from the latest version of chrome -> [Read more](https://chromestatus.com/feature/6750456638341120)

Answer (score 39):

Make sure not to miss the explanation of `:host-context` which is directly above `::ng-deep` in the angular guide : https://angular.io/guide/component-styles. I missed it up until now and wish I'd seen it sooner.

`::ng-deep` is often necessary when you didn't write the component and don't have access to its source, but `:host-context` can be a very useful option when you do.

For example I have a black `<h1>` header inside a component I designed, and I want the ability to change it to white when it's displayed on a dark themed background.

If I didn't have access to the source I may have to do this in the css for the parent:

```
.theme-dark widget-box ::ng-deep h1 { color: white; }
```

But instead with `:host-context` you can do this *inside* the component.

```
 h1 
 {
     color: black;       // default color

     :host-context(.theme-dark) &
     {
         color: white;   // color for dark-theme
     }

     // OR set an attribute 'outside' with [attr.theme]="'dark'"

     :host-context([theme='dark']) &
     {
         color: white;   // color for dark-theme
     }
 }
```

This will look anywhere in the component chain for `.theme-dark` and apply the css to the h1 if found. This is a good alternative to relying too much on `::ng-deep` which while often necessary is somewhat of an anti-pattern.

In this case the `&` is replaced by the `h1` (that's how sass/scss works) so you can define your 'normal' and themed/alternative css right next to each other which is very handy.

Be careful to get the correct number of `:`. For `::ng-deep` there are two and for `:host-context` only one.

Comment: You can also use `:host(.theme-dark)` if you don't want to inherit `theme-dark` from any parent components. This will entirely depend on your site css design. Also attributes can be very useful and can be combined in sophisticated ways in css alone `:host([theme='dark']:not([dayofweek='tuesday'))`

Comment: Also note that this follows normal css rules, so if you have a component as described above (with host-context css) inside a container which has a `.theme-light` class this is in turn nested inside a container with `.theme-dark` it will still pick up the `theme-dark` and apply the css. But this is a great solution for 'modernizr' type classes, or if you have a theme set globally and only once.

Comment: Can I use :host-context instead of ::ng-deep ?

Comment: @eddy I’m too sleepy right now to fully think this through, but host-context is almost like ng-deep but going UP the DOM tree instead of down. So it’s absolutely not equivalent but you could

Answer (score 2):

Just an update:

You should use `::ng-deep` instead of `/deep/` which seems to be deprecated.

Per documentation:

> The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is
>   being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop
>   support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep). Until
>   then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with
>   the tools.

You can find it [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

Comment: In this text it clearly says ::ng-deep is also deprecated: "we plan to drop support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep)".

Answer (score 0):

I looked through all those answers and found nobody mentioned a child component can pass a style CSS in from its parent.

In component ts file, you can use this:

```
   @Input() styles: any = {};
```

In component html file, you use this:

```
[ngStyle]="styles"
```

in parent, you use this :

```
<yourComponent [styles]="{backgroundColor: 'blue', 'font-size': '16px'}">
```

Please see more details here: [Best way to pass styling to a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734073/best-way-to-pass-styling-to-a-component)

In this way, we didn't break encapsulation, which is one of those most important  Object orientation principles

Answer (score -5):

Use ::ng-deep with caution.  I used it throughout my app to set the material design toolbar color to different colors throughout my app only to find that when the app was in testing the toolbar colors step on each other.  Come to find out it is because these styles becomes global, see [this article](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)  Here is a working code solution that doesn't bleed into other components.

```
<mat-toolbar #subbar>
...
</mat-toolbar>

export class BypartSubBarComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('subbar', { static: false }) subbar: MatToolbar;
  constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2) { }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer.setStyle(
      this.subbar._elementRef.nativeElement, 'backgroundColor', 'red');
  }

}
```