# How to style the material checkbox in angular ?

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox

This is the mat-checkbox in `Angular` that has wrong style(in the picture).
How can I keep the small checkbox only?
[Click here to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wns8e.png)

Comment: Please add what you tried to create a checkbox ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use ::ng-deep in your CSS file. (ps. [How and where to use ::ng-deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786986/how-and-where-to-use-ng-deep))

Example:

```
::ng-deep mat-checkbox.yourcheckbox .mat-checkbox-frame{
   border: 0px;
}
```

StackBlitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5j1aur?file=app%2Fcheckbox-configurable-example.css