# How does ng-deep work internally in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to figure out how exactly ::ng-deep selector works. How does it omit random nghost and ngcontent attributes names?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean that it "omits" them?

Comment: Sorry, I expressed myself vaguely. I just do not understand how ng:deep make it possible to reach inner elements of children components. How exactly does it work?

Answer (score 1):

if you use `::ng-deep` in a component where view encapsulation is turned off, it stays there. Since this is invalid CSS, some rules break. It's silent and partial failure because CSS parser simply sees `::ng-deep` as unknown selector.

If we want our component styles to cascade to all child elements of a component, but not to any other element on the page, we can currently do so using by combining the `:host` with the `::ng-deep` selector.

```
:host ::ng-deep h2 {
    color: red;
}
```

FYI: The `::ng-deep` pseudo-class selector also has a couple of aliases: `>>>` and `/deep/`, and all three are soon to be removed.

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/

[How and Where to use ::ng-deep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786986/how-and-where-to-use-ng-deep)

Comment: Thanks for your anwer. However, it still does not explain HOW it works. AFAIK, when we have ViewEncapsulation set to Emulated, then every element  in component get its attribute: ng-conent-<unique_string> and then component's styles are being rewritten for example: div[ng-contnent-1]: {...}. I still do not understand how ng-deep works and how does it make it possible to style children elements