# Angular - Dropdown appears below modal

Tags: css, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

I developed an angular autocomplete, but I thought it didn't work ...

I found that the problem was that the dropdown appears under Modal ...

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Thank you !

**My Stackblitz**

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gvkl6l)

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#taskM">
    Open modal
  </button>

<div class="modal fade animate" id="taskM" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-scrollable modalTask" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content modelTask">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <p class="heading Catitle">
              New 
            </p>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true" class="white-text">×</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">


         <mat-form-field style="position:absolute;">
  <mat-chip-list #chipList>
    <mat-chip
        *ngFor="let engineer of chipSelectedEngineers"
        [selectable]=true
        [removable]=true
        (removed)="removeEngineer(engineer)">
        {{engineer.fullName}}
        <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <input
        placeholder="Users"
        #engineerInput
        [formControl]="engineerControl"
        [matAutocomplete]="auto"
        [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
        [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
        [matChipInputAddOnBlur]=true
        (matChipInputTokenEnd)="addEngineer($event)">
  </mat-chip-list>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="engineerSelected($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let thisEngineerName of filteredEngineers | async" [value]="thisEngineerName">
        {{thisEngineerName}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your modals z-index is `1050` whereas the container for the drop down's z-index is `1000`.

If you change the css for the drop down class to `1051`, it'll be above the modal.

```
.cdk-overlay-container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1051;
}
```

Comment: I tested it and it didn't work :( Can you see my stackblitz to see if I did something wrong?

Comment: Add `::ng-deep` before `.cdk-overlay-container`, as the overlay is appended to `body` element, it's not a descendant of your component.

Comment: In my case the drop-down values are getting displayed outside the modal popup. How do I resolve that issue?

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that both the modal and options have  `z-index: 1040;` you need to increase the options z-index.
so you need to add

```
.cdk-overlay-container {
  z-index: 1050;
}
```

preferably in your globale css *(for me it just won't work only if it's on globale css)*

**Edit** 
after @Harry and @AndreiGheorghiu comment the best practice is:

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container {
  z-index: 1050;
 }
```

you can learn more about `::ng-deep` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46787145/5519980) answer and the official [docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host-context).

Comment: Missing :: ng-deep and perfect !

Comment: @Harry isn't deprecated ?

Comment: @ChiKa, it's not deprecated and will ***never*** be deprecated. Do not confuse `/deep/` (or `>>>`) with `::ng-deep`. `::ng-deep` (like `::v-deep` in Vue) is an internal Angular `scss` combinator which just tells the compiler to translate `::ng-deep .selector { /* rules */ }` into `.selector { /* rules */ }` instead of `_ngcontent-r@nd0m .selector { /* rules */ }`. Unlike the alternatives, `::ng-deep` never makes it into css and does not need browser support. So it's not affected by Chrome's [deprecation of `/deep/`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/remove-shadow-piercing).

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu well thank you i edited my response, a github debate got me confused.

Comment: Everyone's confused about this, including Angular team members. Considering its usage and its lack of viable alternatives (as far as SPS go), `::ng-deep` is not removable without a significant decrease in Angular market share. If it does get removed (at the soonest it would be in Angular 10), it would be a huge marketing blunder. I exaggerated when I said *"never"*, but it's quite unlikely, at least for now.

Comment: well this article say it would be removed too https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/ but who knows #justswitchtovue

Comment: That article claims `/deep/` and `>>>` are aliases of `::ng-deep`. Simply use each and compare results. Naming yourself *"angular-university"* doesn't make you an angular expert.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change z-index to higher number.
To make sure it works, set !important to it as below.

```
.cdk-overlay-container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1052 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these css to you **app.component.css**:

```
::ng-deep .modal-backdrop.fade.in{ z-index: 999 !important; }
::ng-deep .modal { z-index: 1000 !important; }
```

complete working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5sv8s2)

Comment: I downvoted for use of `!important`. It's bad practice, therefore should not be used in [SO] answers, except when needing to override inline styles, added by JavaScript.