# Angular components how to use stylesheet defined be the user?

Tags: html, css, node.js, angular, components

Assumed I have created an Angular component called `button` and I want the user, who implements it in their app to set the color of the button. Is there a other way than using `Input()` decorators?

Comment: Assuming that, for example, the color of the button in the component is holded by a variable you can use `@viewChild` to get the istance of the button component and use `this.button.color = yourColor;` (Or even within a method). I don't get it why `@Input` is not ok. You could also use `ng::deep` but it's getting deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Input` decorator is the best in this situation, for ex. :

button.component.html:

```
<button class="your-custom-buttom" [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: color}">Button</button>
```

button.component.ts:

```
 @Input() color = 'red'
```

app.component.html:

```
<app-button color="green"></app-button>
```

Other way, you could add some specific class to button component, and tell user to change it in styles.scss:

styles.scss:

```
.your-custom-buttom {
  background-color: red;
}
```

button.component.html:

```
<button class="your-custom-buttom">button</button>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dyrn4f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton%2Fbutton%2Fbutton.component.html

Answer (score 2):

The only alternative way that I'm were of is using [ng::deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786986/how-and-where-to-use-ng-deep). But remember, this feature will become [deprecated](http://ng-deep%20deprecated) soon!

Follows an example of how to use it.

`app.component.html`:

```
<my-component>
   <another-component>
      <div class="buton"></div>
   </another-component>
</my-component>
```

`my-component.component.scss`:

```
.someclasse ::ng-deep {
     .button {
         background-color: white;
     }
}
```