# the shortest way to set font-weight:bold; to a content of the component

Tags: css, angular, sass

What should I write into scss file to set `font-weight: bold;` for the innner content of the component (so that the inner tags inherit it)?
using

```
:host {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

does this work but it makes it for the component tag itself as well.

What's the best technique in this case? 
Also, I would avoid to stick with using div, p, span or whatever tag is a child of the component tag.

Thank you.

Comment: please include a sample of your code. Are you nesting components?

Comment: For selecting child component's tags, you can use ::ng-deep see:    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786986/how-and-where-to-use-ng-deep

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`universal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) selector. Inside your component .scss place:

```
* {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

The angular compiler will add the content host tag to the selector, which will result in something like `*[_ngcontent-uch-c0]`.

Using the wildcard could have some performance impact though, so use carefully

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off encapsulation of the component

```
@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Take care if you do this then all global style could apply on the DOM inside of your component.