# Angular ::ng-deep not working in global style

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I created a component with its style I inserted

```
::ng-deep .input-blue.mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
  color: #6200EE !important;
}
```

works perfectly. However when I add this code to the global style to use it in all components not working.

Comment: FYI ::ng-deep is about to deprict, please avoid its usage

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How and where to use ::ng-deep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786986/how-and-where-to-use-ng-deep)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The global `style.css` is just a plain, non-Angular, or at least non-encapsulated (that is its whole point) style sheet. Remove the `::ng-deep` and just leave

```
.input-blue.mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
  color: #6200EE !important;
}
```