# PrimeNG: Change the background color of selected button

Tags: angular, sass, primeng

I'm using PrimeNG `selectButton` component. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/selectbutton. I can't find a way to change the blue background color of the selected button, to a different one.

[image]

This is my html code

```
<p-selectButton [options]="brands" multiple="multiple" >
                    <ng-template let-car let-i="index" pTemplate="item">
                        <div class="brand-image-container">
                            <img id="{{car.value}}" src="./assets/images/png/brand-logos//{{car.label}}.png">
                        </div>
                    </ng-template>
                </p-selectButton>
```

And this is my scss:

```
::ng-deep {
  .ui-selectbutton .ui-button.ui-state-default {
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: solid 0 transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
}

::ng-deep {
   .ui-selectbutton .ui-button.ui-state-active {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
::ng-deep {
       .ui-selectbutton .ui-button.ui-state-highlight {
            background-color: green;
        }
    }
```

Only the **default** **state** is working.

Any help on why **highlight** and **active states** are not working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with these classes:

```
::ng-deep {
  .p-selectbutton .p-button.p-highlight {
    background: red;
    background-color: red;
  }

  .p-selectbutton .p-button.p-highlight:hover {
    background: green;
  }
}
```

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-selectbutton-demo-ap7h1z?file=src/app/app.component.scss)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that did not work, i updated my question for more details

Comment: I don't understand, is something not working in my StackBlitz? Have you tried to replace your CSS prefixes`.ui-` with `.p-`?

Comment: It's working on StackBlitz but not when i integrate it with my code, that's weird ..

Comment: Can you share a picture of your DOM when you inspect your selectbutton?

Comment: Yes thank you it was not the right DOM i used in my scss. Thanks a lot.

Comment: the `::ng-deep` does work, but could you explain in your original answer why?

Comment: It's used to override CSS. For more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786986/how-and-where-to-use-ng-deep

Comment: @Antikhippe How could I change the color of the button according to the option selected. For example, if user selects 'on' the button color turns green and if user selects 'off' the button color turns red?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i used to meet bug like you, it may be in your project have a different class when active.
Example: In stackBlitz it will ->

```
    ::ng-deep .p-selectbutton .p-button.p-highlight {
    color: #007ad9 !important;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
```

But in my project it will ->

```
    ::ng-deep .ui-selectbutton .ui-button.ui-state-active {
    color: #007ad9 !important;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
```

It works fine for me you can try it. Thanks

Comment: This Question is a little bit old, but thanks for your effort anyway