# ng-marquee change background-color

Tags: angular, marquee

No matter I tried the following codes, the background-color still not works. Is there any way to change it?

The package I installed:
https://developer.aliyun.com/mirror/npm/package/ng-marquee/v/1.0.1

```
<ng-marquee [stopOnHover]="true" duration="40s" direction="alternate" bgcolor="#212529" > Test </ng-marquee>
```

or

Component:

```
<ng-marquee [stopOnHover]="true" duration="40s" direction="alternate" class="Color"> Test </ng-marquee>
```

CSS:

```
.Color { background-color: #212529; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JBoothUA reply. ::ng-deep is the solve

Component:

```
<ng-marquee [stopOnHover]="true" duration="40s" direction="alternate" class="marquee">
    Test
</ng-marquee>
```

CSS:

```
.marquee { 
    ::ng-deep {
        .ng-marquee {
            background-color: #292059; 
            color: white;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in order for your css to effect inner libraries you'll probably have to use the ::ng-deep selector.

[What to use in place of ::ng-deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024236/what-to-use-in-place-of-ng-deep/49308475#49308475)

[How and where to use ::ng-deep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786986/how-and-where-to-use-ng-deep)