# ionic 5 "CSS Custom Properties" --background image cover and repeat

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic4, ionic5

i'm using ionic 5, i'm trying to **cover** the image background and make it **not-repeat**, so in ionic 5 i dont know if its possible

usualy i do like this:

```
background-image: url(assets/BGpaper-01.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

Using ionic they have custom css property for ionic components, for example:

**ion-action-sheet**, the background must be like this:

```
--background: url(assets/BGpaper-01.png);
```

for **no-repeat** and **cover** i try this:

```
ion-action-sheet {
--background: url(assets/BGpaper-01.png) no-repeat center center / cover;
}
```

*but seems not work for me*

Comment: Ionic makes have use of the shadow DOM. Have you tried appending ::ng-deep ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786986/how-and-where-to-use-ng-deep

Comment: try using --background:none before using the above properties

Comment: for example: ion-content {
    --background: none;
    background-image: url('../images/img_name.jpg');
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
--background: url(../../../assets/images/bg.png) 0 0/100% 100% no-repeat;
```

Comment: Care to explain how this helps?

Answer (score 0):

```
 background: url('../../../../assets/imgs/bg2.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        background-size:cover;
```