# Overriding global css in a new component Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I need some help on CSS since my CSS is very rusty. So I am working on a project which has a couple of global CSS files and they have properties defined for various tags (ex-> .btn). I am using an external library called Form.io in my project but those global CSS files are messing up the CSS files from the library Form.io since some of the classes are already defined in the global CSS file. Is there a way to override those specific classes so that the Form.io library uses its own CSS-defined properties and not the global CSS properties?

I tried using the :not() in the global CSS file for certain classes that I think are affecting the Form.io library but doing so affects other pages and their style so that is something I don't want. Any help or suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `!important` in the end of your `CSS` rule to ovverride global styles.

Example:

```
.btn {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Doing that alone doesn't seem to work but I also have to add :host ::ng-deep. Is that a good practice to follow?

Comment: @Shalin - There's no peoblem with that since you are using `:host` before `::ng-deep`.

Comment: Angular 10 - Avoid using ::ng-deep (ngdeep) [deprecated]:https://dev.to/jwp/angular-10-ng-deep-and-host-pseudo-classes-1kbg

Comment: @JuanBerzosaTejero - Could you please provide an alternative? `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` is not practical either, this had a long discussion here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786986/how-and-where-to-use-ng-deep) but not one useful answer regarding deprecation of `::ng-deep`.