# Overriding element's css in Nebular/Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, overriding, nebular

So I am trying to change the css of the header element of the nebular theme in angular

[It looks like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4Ku4.png)

[I want it to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnIW6.png)

I am trying to separate the two elements (the "MyApp" and the actions bar). Through the console I found that I had to change the "justify-content" of the nav element embeded in the nb-header-layout to "space-between". Here is what I did

html:

```html
<nb-layout-header class="header1">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <app-actions-bar></app-actions-bar>
</nb-layout-header>
```

css:

```css
.header1 nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

But the changes doesn't apply. Why? And how should I do it?

I looked into not using Nebular’s layout header but it seems like nebular is forcing you to use it otherwise it is not displayed.

Comment: can you share your code on online editors?

Answer (score 0):

did you make sure the CSS loading order is correct? If one component has shared CSS in two different files, the older one will rewrite by the newer one

Comment: Yes, the css loading order is correct and the header1 class is unique

Comment: You may share more of your code then...

Answer (score 0):

I think your CSS not applying can you please replace your CSS like this:

```
.header1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late, but try using [::ng-deep](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

It can be used to force your styles down to a child element, useful in this case because the element you want to apply styling to, the `nav`, is not included in your markdown. For example:

```css
::ng-deep nb-layout-header nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

Relevant StackOverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786986/how-and-where-to-use-ng-deep).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is like Laurence said

```
::ng-deep nb-layout-header nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).