# How to correctly target a element that is using ng-deep

Tags: css, angular

I'm into a project an offshore team has set up and for some reason one of the containers is set up in a way that I can only edit some of the CSS using ::NG-Deep in the SCSS file, however I don't want this to affect anyway else on the project but rather this one page, what is the correct way to do this?

Right now I have this:

```
::ng-deep .main-panel .full-content{
    min-height: 50%;
  }
```

But this is not best practice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How and where to use ::ng-deep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786986/how-and-where-to-use-ng-deep)

Answer (score 0):

Use `:host` to avoid it:

```scss
:host ::ng-deep .main-panel .full-content{
  min-height: 50%;
}
```