# I am using prime ng with angular in my project and want to change the label color of dropdown to gery when [readonly]=true

Tags: angular, primeng, angular13, property-binding, primeng-dropdowns

I am trying to change the label color of p-dropdown when the readonly property is true.

I want to change the color of the label to grey when the property [readonly] is  true using css or any other method.

Comment: When you say "label color of p-dropdown", do you mean the color of the placeholder?

Comment: You can use `ng-deep` https://stackoverflow.com/q/46786986/11561695