# dateClass is getting the css class name but it does not apply the style on the datepicker

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, datepicker

I'm trying to apply a css changes on a specific dates in a datepicker in angular

I tried this but it did not work, using 'console.log(highlightDate);' gave that dateClass() returns the right dates but the style does not apply

html

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
     <mat-label>Date de retour</mat-label>
   <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" [(ngModel)]="date_retour"  name="inputcalendar2">
   <mat-hint>MM/JJ/YYYY</mat-hint>
   <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
   <mat-datepicker [dateClass]="dateClass" #picker2></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

component.ts

```
highlightedDates = [new Date('04/17/2023'), new Date('04/05/2023'), new Date('04/15/2023')];
dateClass = (date: Date): MatCalendarCellCssClasses => {
    var highlightDate = this.highlightedDates.find(d => d.getTime() === date.getTime());
    console.log(highlightDate);
    return highlightDate ? 'highlighted-date' : '';
  }
```

css

```
.highlighted-date 
{  
    background: rgb(224, 245, 255);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [::ng-deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786986/how-and-where-to-use-ng-deep) or maybe this could help [Customizing Angular Material component styles](https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles)