# ::ng-deep getting applied to parent components

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-deep

I was using ::ng-deep to apply classes to the child components but the class is also applied to the parent component of that component.How can i restrict this behaviour?

```
::ng-deep label {
    width: 164px;
    height: 22px;
    font-family: 'Inter';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55356579/12050506

Comment: Try [applying the ng-deep to children only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36528769/19330634)

Comment: I need see your child and parent component. Perhaps you are not spliting the component

Comment: Additional, r1emember ::ng-deep is deprecated, please use component-specific styles instead

Comment: Try adding :host too

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Adding :host with :ng-deep solved my problem.