# Angular material mat-date-range-input input custom position for placeholder

Tags: css, angular-material, datepicker, css-position, angular-daterangepicker

Here is the HTML code :

```
<section class="search-filter-po">
    <form [formGroup]="RequiredFormGroup">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 search-row">
                <span class="d-flex justify-content-center">Creation Date</span>
                <mat-form-field class="set-width">
                    <div class="date_container">
                        <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
                            <input matStartDate formControlName="from_date" placeholder="Start date">
                            <input matEndDate formControlName="to_date" placeholder="End date" (dateInput)="incrementFilterCount()">
                        </mat-date-range-input>
                        <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                        <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
                    </div>
                    <mat-error *ngIf="POFormGroup.controls.from_date.hasError('matStartDateInvalid')">Invalid start date</mat-error>
                    <mat-error *ngIf="POFormGroup.controls.to_date.hasError('matEndDateInvalid')">Invalid end date</mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
```

Here is the CSS code :

```
.date_container {
    float: right;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.mat-date-range-input {
    border: 0px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0%;
}
.set-width {
    width : 100%;
}
```

If you reproduce the above you'll get the placeholder aligned to the top left corner as depicted in the picture below.

[image]

I want to centre align the placeholder such that it is aligned with the calender icon. In case you are facing any difficulties in reproducing the error here is the [Stackbltiz working example](https://stackblitz.com/github/manojvaadulasa/placeholderPositionError?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: You may find this answer helpful ng-deep helpful. See this answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786986/how-and-where-to-use-ng-deep
Here is the link in the docs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786986/how-and-where-to-use-ng-deep
Unfortunately, it is deprecated, but I think it's worth mentioning here.

Comment: I have tried ng-deep but it didn't affect the alignement of the placeholder. I think it has to do with the main scss file which I'm unable to override with the scss file of my component.

Comment: A component's stylesheets override global stylesheets included in angular.json, I believe.

Comment: I tried reproducing the issue in a stackblitz. The URL is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-imesbp?file=src%2Fmain.ts
What I see is different from the screenshot posted in the question. I believe this is due to theming and not your fault, Manoj. I will let you know if and when I get past that roadblock. In the meantime, I thought I would share the URL, in case there is something I clearly did wrong in trying to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I noticed in my (imperfect) reproduction of the issue that I had no elements in the generated HTML (the HTML I inspected in my browser) that match the CSS selector ".mat-date-range-input". That selector is a class selector. I will note that there were numerous classes with similar names, including "mat-date-range-input-container" and "mat-date-range-input-wrapper". My guess is that you were not trying to write a class selector, though. I think you wanted an element selector like "mat-date-range-input" (just dropped the preceding period), which selects any mat-date-range-input element :)

Comment: The suggested solution did not work but thank you for suggesting. What I observed was that the placeholder is linked to the mat-form-field and in order to align it I need to link it with the date-container styling. I tried to link the date-container class with the mat-form-field itself but the calender icon got displaced and started to show in the next row.

Comment: If you are unable to reproduce the error, then I'm at fault. I'll edit the question and update it with more details.

Comment: Please tell me if you can reproduce the error. I've updated the question with some more details now.

Comment: With the stackblitz you provided, I was able to reproduce the issue.