# How to deal with /deep/ selector in a react application when migrating from node-sass to sass?

Tags: reactjs, sass, dart-sass

I'm migrating an old react application with a bunch of scoped scss files (using [scoped-css-loader](https://github.com/gaoxiaoliangz/react-scoped-css) in conjunction with sass-loader in webpack) from node-sass to dart sass.

Obviously, i have a lot of /deep/ selectors in those files which has no support in dart sass. I would like to migrate "smoothly" and avoid to rewrite the whole application style before being able to swith the lib.
In a medium term, the goal is to remove those deep selectors bit by bit. In the meantime, i'm looking for an alternative so that i can migrate the lib and then remove the selector during a few iterations.

I've seen that there are alternatives for Vue (https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3399) with v-deep and for angular ([How and where to use ::ng-deep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786986/how-and-where-to-use-ng-deep)) with ng-deep

What about react ? Are you aware of a project which adds support for it ?

Anyway, thanks for your help

Comment: Actually, looking at scoped-css-loader code, it seems that internally the loader uses @vue/component-compiler-utils.this means we should be able ti use the ::v-deep pseudo element. Unfortunately, since sass-loader kicks in first, it logs that the v-deep pseudo element is not recognized.

Comment: https://github.com/gaoxiaoliangz/react-scoped-css/pull/60